# Can an AJAX response set a cookie?

Tags: ajax, cookies

Can an AJAX response set a cookie?  If not, what is my alternative solution?  Should I set it with Javascript or something similar?

Comment: I am using node.js Express. I noticed that if you do that, you have to set the httpOnly field to false at the server side too apparently.

Answer (score 266, accepted):

**Yes**, you can set cookie in the AJAX request in the server-side code just as you'd do for a normal request since the server cannot differentiate between a normal request or an AJAX request.

AJAX requests are just a special way of requesting to server, the server will need to respond back as in any HTTP request. In the response of the request you can add cookies.

Comment: Keep in mind that whether the cookie will be honored by the HTTP agent is another story.

Comment: @Franci: agreed. But I think the question only makes sense for http clients that support cookie. So all question-asker only wishes to know if cookies can be written in AJAX request that means his UA supports cookies :)

Comment: `If the user agent supports HTTP State Management it should persist, discard and send cookies (as received in the Set-Cookie response header, and sent in the Cookie header) as applicable.` -- from http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/

Comment: If the server can't differenciate between "normal" and ajax request, what is this api for in asp.net: 
   'this.Request.IsAjaxRequest'   :)

Comment: This answers if the server can reply to an ajax request with a Set-Cookie header. And of course it can, but the question is whether that response will actually result in that the client reads and sets the cookie received in the ajax response, or if it has to be done manually. This is not an answer for that.

Comment: @Legends Ajax requests usually have the X-Requested-With header set to XMLHttpRequest, this is how they can be identified, but a request can be made without this header, if this happens it cannot be distinguished from a normal page load

Answer (score 318):

According to the [w3 spec section 4.6.3 for XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest) a user agent should honor the Set-Cookie header. So the answer is yes you should be able to.

Quotation:

> If the user agent supports HTTP State Management it should persist,
>   discard and send cookies (as received in the Set-Cookie response
>   header, and sent in the Cookie header) as applicable.

Comment: Does IE support the Set-Cookie header in responses, in case of XHR responses?

Comment: As it should on a redirect, and it does not honor in some browsers.

Comment: For me using Chrome, headers received in ajax requests will automatically get applied to the client.

Comment: I found that if server side is setting back the response as gzip, the cookie doesn't get set. Is that supposed to be part of the spec or is that just an implementation issue?

Answer (score 96):

For the record, be advised that all of the above is (still) true only if the AJAX call is made on the same domain. If you're looking into setting cookies on another domain using AJAX, you're opening a totally different [can of worms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#Requests_with_credentials). Reading cross-domain cookies does work, however (or at least the server serves them; whether your client's UA allows your code to access them is, again, a different topic; as of 2014 they do).

Comment: To send cross-domain cookies, you need to set the [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#Requests_with_credentials) flag

Comment: For cross-domain scenario, 3 things need to happen:- (1) Client needs to set `withCredentials=true` for the `xhr` object (2) Set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` both in the OPTIONS preflight request as well as the actual request (3) Set the cookie as needed

Answer (score 6):

Also check that your server isn't setting secure cookies on a non http request.  Just found out that my ajax request was getting a php session with "secure" set.  Because I was not on https it was not sending back the session cookie and my session was getting reset on each ajax request.

Comment: can you tell me , where i can check is ajax secure is set ?

Comment: It's not really ajax specific. Check for "Secure" in the Set-Cookie header response from the server if you are using insecure http://