# Laravel 4: reading cookies set by javascript

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

If I set a cookie with javascript, how would I read it using Laravel 4?

The reason I'm asking is that the docs say:

```
All cookies created by the Laravel framework are encrypted and signed 
with an authentication code, meaning they will be considered invalid 
if they have been changed by the client.
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/DragonI/4450164 is interesting. For now I'm relying on https://stackoverflow.com/a/14979105/470749

Comment: Apparently the cleaner way to handle it in Laravel 5.6: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49578508/470749

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just use the native PHP command to retrieve cookies: `$_COOKIE['cookie'])`

Or perhaps you can set the cookie via an AJAX command (rather than JS doing it itself) - and have Laravel set the cookie supplied by JS on its behalf?

[This link confirms setting cookies via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3340797/1317935) - it will just be a variation of that.

Comment: Any idea how I could do the reverse? Set a cookie in Laravel that javascript can read?

I tried `$_COOKIE['cookie']` with no luck

Answer (score 21):

In Laravel 5.6 (and maybe earlier versions too):

Specify the cookie name in the `$except` array within `App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php`.

It tells Laravel that those cookies aren't encrypted (and therefore don't need to be decrypted when read).

(P.S. Thanks to https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/460#issuecomment-377537771)

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.4 and this middleware is also available, trace back in document in think it's introduced since Laravel 5.1

Comment: Works in Laravel 7 as well