# Laravel can't access all cookies

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, cookies, jquery-cookie

I'm using `laravel 5.6` and cookie to use data across pages.

In my first page N°1, I have a table with button like this :

```
<button data-href="/fractions/" data-lot="1" class="link m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-brand m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" title="Fractions">
    <i class="la la-puzzle-piece"></i>
</button>
```

And I have a script attachi to .link :

```
$(document).on('click', '.link', function(e){
    $.cookie("lot", $(this).data("lot"), { expires: 7 });
    $(location).attr('href',$(this).data("href"));
});
```

On my second page N°2 (data-href), I use :

```
{{ Cookie::get('lot') }}
```

But nothing shows up. I looked inside chrome console and I can see my cookie.

I try to debug on the controller side but it doesn't see the cookie too.

What's weird is that I use the same system at the beginning of my site (page N°0) and on page N°2 I can access to the cookie I create on page N°0.

So why I can access all cookies?

Thank for your help.

Comment: You are adding data to cookie from front end and don't push it to server. You should make a ajax call and ask server to add cookie instead.

Comment: So why can I access to the cookie from the beginning that I added with this kind of function

Comment: Are they the same origin & path?  Show the cookie in the dev console and the link you are using.

Comment: Laravel encrypts its cookies so if you create one in javascript laravel wont recognize it. Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975751/laravel-4-reading-cookies-set-by-javascript

Comment: @MarcusNordin it works !! Thank a lot !

Answer (score 1):

> path: '/'
>
> Define the path where the cookie is valid. By default the path of the cookie is the path of the page where the cookie was created (standard browser behavior). If you want to make it available for instance across the entire domain use path: '/'. Default: path of page where the cookie was created.

Create expiring cookie, valid across entire site:

```
$.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

Source: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#readme

---

For Laravel, since it uses Cookie Encryption, consult [Laravel 4: reading cookies set by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975751/laravel-4-reading-cookies-set-by-javascript)

Comment: Same problem :/

Comment: So, this was probably an issue because the path changed, but the main issue was Laravel's encryption of cookies it looks like.