# Cookie not stored with Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies

I am going crazy with cookies and ajax call.

My configuration is simple. I run a website on 8282 port, (localhost.com:8282). My website calls some webservices on 8080 port (localhost.com:8080). Of course I add a line in my hosts file to avoid localhost trouble :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.com
```

I try to set a cookie when the webservice is called with ajax. Here is my response header that I can see with Chrome debugger :

```
Set-Cookie:token=Custom eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOiIxNDI0NzE5Mzc5ODY3IiwgImlkIjoiNTRlNzZkZGU2ZDk3ZGM1MjYxZjQzMzFlIiwgInNpZ25hdHVyZSI6Im5tZnFGeEEvYlc0TFJGNFJNb3dBZXJZOUw0aWw0aEorcFh1YUt5b3VFK0k9In0=;domain=.localhost.com;path=/;
```

The cookie is never stored by Chrome. However, when I use [Rest client extension](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) and I call the same webservice, the cookie is stored by Chrome ! So my cookie is well formed but is not stored with ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely an issue with CORS (*Cross Origin Resource Sharing*, i.e the fact that the domain of the client and of the target of the AJAX call are not the same). For cookies to work well in a CORS configuration, you need to set the `withCredentials` flag to `true`. How to do so varies depending on you AJAX library (if you're using one).

See here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Thank you for your help, is it considered as CORS issue even if the domain is the same and only the port change ?

Answer (score 0):

In your close reponse of ajax you can set your cookie

```js
document.cookie = "token=Custom eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOiIxNDI0NzE5Mzc5ODY3IiwgImlkIjoiNTRlNzZkZGU2ZDk3ZGM1MjYxZjQzMzFlIiwgInNpZ25hdHVyZSI6Im5tZnFGeEEvYlc0TFJGNFJNb3dBZXJZOUw0aWw0aEorcFh1YUt5b3VFK0k9In0=;domain=.localhost.com;path=/";
```

[Can an AJAX response set a cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340797/can-an-ajax-response-set-a-cookie)