# How to set cookies for other domain with AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, http-headers

Let’s assume I own 2 web apps hosted on `foo.com` and `bar.com`. `bar.com` allows cross origin requests from `foo.com`

Is it possible to set a cookie for `bar.com` by making an ajax request from `foo.com` to `bar.com`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can an AJAX response set a cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340797/can-an-ajax-response-set-a-cookie)

Comment: @nice_dev ok I see it now

Comment: @Romalex Your question doesn't make sense since end user is always going to be on `foo.com`. So setting a cookie on `bar.com` is futile.  Also, requesting site can't enforce any set cookie operations on the responding site.

Comment: @nice_dev The end user will be redirected to `bar.com` at some point

Comment: Also, is it really impossible? Can `withCredentials` flag possibly do the trick?

Comment: @Romalex Do you have access to `bar.com` code wise?

Comment: @nice_dev, i do

Comment: @Romalex You can add a setting in DB for a particular user when the ajax request is made and set cookies from `bar.com` when they visit it.